# Maven add dependencies on runtime

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to compile and run this java project using maven. For this, Ive had to use a 3rd party Jar library, not found in the maven repository. I've been trying to tell maven to use this library on runtime (since it works perfectly fine at compile time, as I stated it on the POM file with no issues). I've tried several things such as using the [Add-Jars plugin](https://code.google.com/p/addjars-maven-plugin/), adding it on the POM file as an external dependency:

```
        <!--medpost-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>lib.medpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>medpost</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/medpost/medpost/1.0/medpost.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Among other things such as trying to indicate it as a command line argument, such as the first optional argument as shown in this [API](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#additionalClasspathElements). It still throws a ClassNotFoundException. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you see this jar in m2?

Comment: Its actually a list of Jar dependencies from [BANNER](https://sites.google.com/site/bannerintrotutorial/). Some can be found on the maven repositories (such as medpost) but other more crucial ones like [DragonTools](http://dragon.ischool.drexel.edu/features.asp) are not in the central repository. I even found this [Github repository](https://github.com/oaqa/banner) which is unfortunately partly broken as the depedencies will not work.

Comment: Navigate to C:\Users\jlazo\.m2\repository\ in your Windows explorer.  Look for a folder called `medpost`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to install the custom JAR into your local Maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=medpost.jar 
    -DgroupId=lib.medpost -DartifactId=medpost -Dversion=1.0
```

Then just put the following standard `<dependency>` into your POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>lib.medpost</groupId>
    <artifactId>medpost</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

By default, the `medpost.jar` will be available for both compilation **and** runtime, so you don't need to specify a scope unless you have a special need other than what your OP stated.

By the way, the likely reason you weren't having a problem during compilation is that your *IDE* had the JAR on its classpath.  But when *you* actually tried running it, the dependency was not available.

Comment: I tried that command (maven also requires a -Dpackaging as well, I used  =jar) and I still get  an error. In this case its checking it against the repository:
`Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.gsc:entrez-parsing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact lib.medpost:medpost.jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

Comment: Nevermind, I found my mistake, I was not using the exact name on the groupId. It works now! thanks

Comment: I needed to include -Dpackaging=jar with the the mvn install command to make it work